# How can I fade out a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to fadeout a div after 5 Seconds without using a setTimeOut function?

Comment: Do you want the animation to take 5 seconds or do you want to wait 5 seconds before the animation starts?

Comment: Yes i want to wait 5 seconds before the animation starts.
It's solved, I wrote function a $("div").fadeOut(10000); then it is working as what i want to do exactly!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

everyone knows that in jquery 1.4 there's a delay function now, right?

```
$('#div').delay(5000).fadeOut(400)
```

that's how you do it, without having to add any custom functions or plug-ins. it's native to jquery 1.4

Answer (score 29):

Case 1: if you want to **start** fadeOut after 5 seconds, use this:

```
jQuery.fn.delay = function(time,func){
    return this.each(function(){
        setTimeout(func,time);
    });
};
```

Then, use it like this:

```
$('#div').delay(5000, function(){$(#div').fadeOut()})
```

You can't achieve this without using setTimeOut at all

Case 2: if you want the **duration** of fadeOut to be 5 seconds, use this:

```
$('#div').fadeOut(5000)
```

Answer (score 20):

How about the [fadeOut()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut) function.  Would look something like this:

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut(5000);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  He wants to fade *after* 5 seconds, not have the fade last *for* 5 seconds.

Comment: i want to wait 5 seconds before the animation starts. It's solved, I wrote function as $("div").fadeOut(10000); then it is working as what i want to do exactly with out using setTimeOut() function.
Thank you!

Comment: Actually fadeout start immediately :(

Comment: I agree with you comments friends, when this question was posted, that time there was no suitable answers for this question and that too i don't want to use setTimeOut() or any other plugins, Okay now i will accept the correct answer for this question. thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem and in my opinion the marked answer doesn't actually really satisfy the question. If one specifies it like

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut(5000);
```

as suggsted, the fading process itself will last for 5 seconds, but not **start** after 5 seconds.

So I was searching for an alternative, without having to include another jQuery plugin etc. The simplest solution I came up with was to write it as follows:

```
$("#myDiv").fadeTo(5000,1).fadeOut(1000);
```

It uses the fadeTo effect and it is somehow a "hack". I let the fadeTo run for 5 seconds and let it fade to 1 = 100% opacity. In this way the user doesn't perceive any change. Afterwards the normal call to fadeOut with a duration of the effect of 1 second.

I guess this solution is quite simple since it doesn't require any additional plugin and can be written in 1 line.

Cheers.

**//EDIT:**
Apparently there is now the possibility to do something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').delay(800).fadeOut(1000);
```

[Here are](http://addyosmani.com/blog/31-jquery-snippets/) some more cool, useful functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want it to take 5 seconds or start in 5 seconds.

For it to take 5 seconds: The jQuery fadeout function can be used on a div, and it will reduce the element's opacity until it is 0 and then display none the div.  The speed of the fade is a parameter for the function.

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback

To start it in 5 seconds, you'll need some sort of timer that starts when the document or window is ready, or when the div is ready depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

// i use this pause plugin i just wrote

```
$.fn.pause = function(duration) {
    $(this).animate({ dummy: 1 }, duration);
    return this;
};
```

Call it like this :

```
$("#mainImage").pause(5000).fadeOut();
```

Note: you don't need a callback.

Comment: for some reason pause(5000).css("opacity", .5) doesn't pause before setting the opacity, but it works for fadeout. anyone care to explain? note: when i said 'plugin i just wrote' i was trying to indicate 'not fully tested' - but it should work for what was asked for

Comment: css() doesn't use the animation queue.  if you want to pause before changing opacity you'd need something like "pause(5000).animate({ 'opacity': 0.5 });

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean 'wait five seconds and then fade out', I think you'll have to use a plugin to force the delay, eg [this one](http://www.evanbot.com/article/jquery-delay-plugin/4)