# How to add fade effects to popup box in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am showing a popup box with jQuery using the `.show()` jQuery function and hiding with `.hide()`.

How do I add *cute* animations to it like fading?

```
// show pop up
$('.mypopup').show();

// hide pop up
$('.mypopup').hide();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fade out a div using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536502/how-can-i-fade-out-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

replace `.show()` with `.fadeIn()` and `.hide()` with `.fadeOut()`

`.show()` and `.hide()` function works on `display:none` and `display:block` property where `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` works the same but with animation.